# Cannot make views of views

Tags: python, sqlite

Using Python I try to access a view of a view:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("test.db")
mydb = conn.cursor()

mydb.execute("CREATE TABLE TestTbl (MRTarget_id int, Fullmodel text)")
mydb.execute("CREATE TABLE TestTbl2 (Other_id int, Othermodel text)")

mydb.execute("CREATE VIEW TestView AS SELECT m.ROWID, m.MRTarget_id, m.Fullmodel, t.Othermodel FROM TestTbl m, TestTbl2 t")
mydb.execute("CREATE VIEW TestView2 AS SELECT m.Fullmodel, m.Othermodel FROM TestView m")

mydb.close()
```

Attempting to create `TestView2`, I get an error:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: m.Fullmodel

Above SQL statements work fine from SQLite prompt. The database contains views of views; could it be that it is not possible to access these using Python?

Comment: Also unable to reproduce this issue, the above code works fine for me.

Comment: Reproduced with this Python: Python 2.6.6 (r266:84297, Aug 24 2010, 18:46:32) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32. OK with Python 2.7.1 on same platform.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem - and I found a solution.  I believe your problem is that in your initial view 'TestView', the attribute names are actually `m.ROWID`, `m.Fullmodel` etc instead of just `ROWID`, `Fullmodel` etc.

A casual look at the views through sqlite manager won't reveal the `m.` appended to the front of each field name.  If you run the Pragma query `PRAGMA table_info TestView`, the attribute extensions will be revealed.

So, change your TestView creation query to

```
CREATE VIEW TestView AS 
SELECT m.ROWID as ROWID, m.MRTarget_id as MRTarget_id,... etc
```

and your second `Create View` query should run successfully - at least it did in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine for me.

You could try committing between creating the first view and the second:

```
conn.commit()
```